# Android Library project out of sync in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, synchronization, adt

I have an Android Library project with some Activities and Views, referenced by an Android Application project. The application project has a "linked" folder marked [Android Library] with the sources of my library project.

One thing that seems strange to me, is that the same source file can be opened twice, from the linked folder and from the original library folder. This often results in files being out on sync, and all sorts of nasty things happening.

Any idea of what's going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior. If the same physical folder is added multiple times via resource links, the synchronization state of each of the folders is tracked separately. Here are your options:

1. Deal with having to manually refresh folders from time to time.
2. Turn on auto-refresh under Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> Refresh automatically. I believe this performs ok Windows, but can be very slow on Linux. Actual performance likely depends on the size of your workspace.
3. Re-structure your projects such that you are not using linked folders to bring in library code. I don't know anything about Android development or ADT, but the standard approach for other Java apps is to add a dependency from app project to library project via Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects.

Comment: That's standard behavior of ADT: it automatically adds link if Android Application project uses Android Library project.

Comment: In that case, I would recommend raising this issue with Google. They aren't following best-practices for configuring Java projects in Eclipse. Linking of folders already present in another Java project not only creates synchronization problems, but also makes Eclipse compile each of the classes twice.

Comment: I don't think its easy to fix, that's because of Android Library specifics. It behaves very different from standard jar libraries. Basically Android Library source files are compiled directly into Android Application. I guess that's why they use this library links, but that just my speculations.

Comment: Very possible to do this right in ADT, but your explanation probably rules out option #3 as a user-applied solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check your package name in Manifest file it should  be same with your project package name.